# Session is showing nothing in homepage (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I'm trying to set session in asp.net app.

Have set `Session("username")=txtusername.text`
in click event of login button and on home page after successful login trying to access the `Session("username")` on page_load but it's getting back to login page as there is nothing in `Session("Username")`.

Can any one help me possible cause as this suddenly started happening.

==========Login page==============

```
                Session("SrNo") = sqlReader.Item(0)
                ViewState("Username") = sqlReader.Item(3)
                Session("Name") = sqlReader.Item(1) + " " + sqlReader.Item(2)
                Session("Mobile") = sqlReader.Item(5)
                Session("Email") = sqlReader.Item(6)
                Session("UserType") = sqlReader.Item(7)
                ' Session.Timeout = "600000"
                Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx", True)
                'Server.Transfer("Welcome.aspx")
            End If
        End If
```

=============Welcome page===================

```
Dim string1 As String
string1 = Session("Username")
If Session("SrNo") = Nothing Then
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
Else
//my codes
endif
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `sqlReader.Item(0)` is not null when you set `Session("SrNo")`?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that sqlReader.Item(0) has value

Comment: Are there any other references `Session("SrNo")` in your solution?

Comment: No, it was working earlier but suddenly don't know what happened it stopped storing sessions.

Even Other sessions are also not working....

Like 
Session("Name") = sqlReader.Item(1) + " " + sqlReader.Item(2)
                Session("Mobile") = sqlReader.Item(5)
                Session("Email") = sqlReader.Item(6)
                Session("UserType") = sqlReader.Item(7)